# NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle doesn't show in iPhone

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm using NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle in my application to convert the date. I display the date on label with font size of 12

It functions on the

> iPad

simulator it show like ***"nov 12,1994"*** but on my

> iPhone

device it shows short formatter: *"11/12/1994"*.

Do you know why it function on the iPad but not in the iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `NSDateFormatterStyle` documentation :

> The format for these date and time styles is not exact because they
>   depend on the locale, user preference settings, and the operating
>   system version. Do not use these constants if you want an exact
>   format.

That said, I assume your iPad and your iPhone are set to different locales

If you want your dates to be as per the iPad example above across all locales, you can create your own formatter

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: so I have to implement an algorithm, Thanks very much

Comment: Hey @Santiagocarmonagonzalez.  See my edit with how to format consistently across locales

Comment: It's not a good idea to hardcode a date format. Users expect to see dates formatted naturally based on their locale. It's much better to use one of the format styles rather than a specific date format.

Comment: @JamesZaghini thanks very much, do you know how tu upper case de month ?. I did what you sugges but the month appear in loweCase, thanks again

Comment: Piece of cake! `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date).uppercaseString`